# How do I compare the date value in this loop to find duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a function that checks for duplicates and remove them using the values in a specified column. If I use any other Column apart from Column A with dates, it works fine, but if I use Column A it doesn't work.

[image]

I understand that the code is not barely referring to the date value and I've tried getTime() and other suggestions but I'm not getting the desired result. Here's my code below

```
function removeDuplicates() { 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row[0] == newData[j][0]) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

I'll be glad to get help to make this code delete duplicate rows based on duplicates found in Column A

Comment: Would be nice if you provide samples of datasets which moves to `data` variable, so anyone could understand what are you working with. Provide datasets for `Column A` and `Column B`, so we can compare why do one work and other don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicateDates() {
  var m=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];//used to convert month to index
  var headerRows=3;//number of header rows
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet177');//change sheet name
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dvA=[];//an array of date values
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  for(var i=headerRows;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var tA=vA[i][0].toString().split(/,| /);//splits on comma or space using a regular expression
    var dv=new Date(tA[3],m.indexOf(tA[1]),tA[2]).valueOf();
    if(dvA.indexOf(dv)==-1) {
      dvA.push(dv);//if current value is not in dvA then it is unique so put it in dvA
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(i+1-d++);//this deletes duplicates based upon a date string in this format Mon,Jul 1,2019 
    }
  }
}
```

This one keeps the last one that matches I think.  It may need some tweaking.

```
function removeDuplicateDates() {
  var m=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];//used to convert month to index
  var headerRows=3;//number of header rows
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet177');//change sheet name
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var dvA=[];//an array of date values
  var rA=[];//a row array
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  for(var i=headerRows;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var tA=vA[i][0].toString().split(/,| /);//splits on comma or space using a regular expression
    var dv=new Date(tA[3],m.indexOf(tA[1]),tA[2]).valueOf();
    var idx=dvA.indexOf(dv);
    if(idx==-1) {
      dvA.push(dv);//if current value is not in dvA then it is unique so put it in dvA
      rA.push(i+1);
    }else{
      sh.deleteRow(rA[idx]-d++);//this deletes duplicates based upon a date string in this format Mon,Jul 1,2019 
      dvA.splice(idx,1);//remove old value
      rA.splice(idx,1);
      dvA.push(dv);//replace with new value
      rA.push(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Cooper, please is there anyway I can tweak it to delete the first duplicate row?

Comment: If you have already look at the second version then copy the latest because I had to add two more lines.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because (and I'm assuming that `row[0]` is a `date` object) two date instances of the exact same date resolve to `false` as can be seen here:

```js
const a = new Date();
const b = new Date(a.getTime());

console.log(a,b);
console.log(a === b);
```

What you should do instead is to compare the `timestamp`:

```js
const a = new Date();
const b = new Date(a.getTime());

console.log(a,b);
console.log(a.getTime() === b.getTime());
```

Thus the change you need to do is the following:

```
if (row[0].getTime() == newData[j][0].getTime()) {
    duplicate = true;
}
```

You can also simplify your loop with the following (no arrow functions, just replace with a normal function):

```
function removeDuplicates() { 

 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 const newData = data.reduce(function(a,row){
   const [currentDate] = row;
   const duplicate = a.every(function([[date]]){
     return date.getTime() !== currentDate.getTime());
   });
   if(!duplicate){
     a.push(row);
   }
   return a;
 }, []);
 sheet.clearContents();
 sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: [tag:google-apps-script] is es5. No arrow functions yet. I believe the rest are ok.

Comment: Hi Kemicofa, I'm getting this error using your simplified code - "Syntax error. (line 5, file "Remove Duplicates")"        " const newData = data.reduce((a,row)=> {"

Comment: so how can I use the timestamp approach with the original function without error. pls help

Comment: @SmithO. the answer is in the first part of my answer.. the simplified function is a bonus and not needed.

Comment: As indicated in my question, I've tried it before, but I'm getting this error - "Cannot find function getTime in object Data. (line 9, file "Remove Duplicates")"

Comment: @SmithO. then what you're working is, is *not* a date because according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates) `getTime` is a method on a date. Could you log `row[0]` and also log `typeof row[0]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197945/discussion-between-smith-o-and-kemicofa).

Comment: @SmithO. , @kemicofa If the active sheet is Entrante2019, Everything is a date except A1, the title, "Date" is a string, which throws off everything. You need to properly get the range or use `.getTime()` only if it is a date